# Automatically sync a local folder to a remote one via FTP using a crontab bash script without sending local open files

Tags: bash, ftp, cron, synchronization

I'm trying to sync a local folder to a remote one using some FTP client parallel sessions (LFTP) started from a linux crontab script. 
Some computational jobs produce (and save in the local dir) the files that will be sent to the FTP server.
I need to verify that the new files saved in the local directory are not still open by the previously mentioned saving processes in order to send only the closed files.
Is there a way to do it? Do you think that the "mirror" option of LFTP command already do this kind of check?

Thank you in advance,
Mauro

Comment: May be this answer can help you:<br>
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70058912/9134997

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to see what you're doing before I can help you fix it, but you could do something like this:

```
# Start of loop over filenames
   # get inode of file
   inode=$( ls -i $file | cut -d' ' -f1 )

   # If file inode does not show up in lsof, run the ftp command in the background
   lsof | grep "$inode" || ftp $file <destination> &

# End of loop
```

Comment: Hi Jack, thank you very much for your support. It works and I will add your code to my script.Anyway, I would like to understand if "mirror" option of LFTP command already do this kind of check... I will try to ask LFTP developers.