# use FTP (only option) to sync files in a directory with a single line command in linux

Tags: ftp, ftp-client

I need to synchronize files in my computer with server to which I have only FTP access and I would prefer a single line to add to crontab which checks every day that new or updated files are transferred (overwritten).

The question has been asked years ago but no simple answer was forthcoming and I want to know if there are better solutions today than `ncftput`, `wput` etc. which do not allow to

```
ncftpput -R -z -u "USER" -p "PASS" webxx.at /dir/ /source/
```

is rumored to work, but the `-z` switch seems "of label" use. My experiments seem to indicate that times are not reliable checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put this code into a file `FtpSync.sh` and add this file into your crontab.
You can adjust the parameters in the file. I tried to create "speaking" parameters so that they explain themselves.
A call of this script will either download or upload files (depending on the parameter `CopyServerdataToLocal`). If you want to do both, simply start the script twice with different parameters (or create two script files).

**`FtpSync.sh`**

```
#!/bin/bash
# Michael Hutter, 20.11.2021
# This Script can be used to synchronize a remote FTP directory and a local directory
HOST='ftp.mywebspace.de'
USER='web1234567f1'
PASS='YourSecretPwd'
SERVERFOLDER='/FolderOnWebspace'
PCFOLDER='/home/michael/ftpsync/MyLocalFolder'
CopyMoreThanOneFileSimultaneously="--parallel=10"

CopyServerdataToLocal=1 # 0=Upload, 1=Download
IgnoreSubdirectories=1
ContinuePartiallyTransmittedFiles=0
DontOverwriteNewerExistingFiles=0 # If this is used ContinuePartiallyTransmittedFiles will not work!

DeleteAdditionalFilesInDestinationDir=0 # Deletes files in DestDir which are not present in SourceDir
RemoveSourceFilesAfterTransfer=0 # Moves the files instead of copying them

ExcludeParams='--exclude-glob .* --exclude-glob .*/' # Exclude (hidden) files and direcories -> starting with a dot

OnlyShowChangesButDontChangeFiles=0 # DryRun mode
OutputAsMuchInfoAsPossible=1 # Verbose mode

################################################################################

if [ $CopyServerdataToLocal -eq 1 ]; then
   if [ $OutputAsMuchInfoAsPossible -eq 1 ]; then
      echo "Modus=Download"
   fi
   DIRECTORIES="$SERVERFOLDER $PCFOLDER"
else
   if [ $OutputAsMuchInfoAsPossible -eq 1 ]; then
      echo "Modus=Upload"
   fi
   REVERSE='--reverse'
   DIRECTORIES="$PCFOLDER $SERVERFOLDER"
fi
if [ $IgnoreSubdirectories -eq 1 ]; then
   IGNORESUBDIRS='--no-recursion'
fi

if [ $ContinuePartiallyTransmittedFiles -eq 1 ]; then
   CONTINUEFILES='--continue'
fi
if [ $DontOverwriteNewerExistingFiles -eq 1 ]; then
   ONLYNEWER='--only-newer'
fi
if [ $DeleteAdditionalFilesInDestinationDir -eq 1 ]; then
   DELETE='--delete'
fi
if [ $RemoveSourceFilesAfterTransfer -eq 1 ]; then
   REMOVE='--Remove-source-files'
fi
if [ $OnlyShowChangesButDontChangeFiles -eq 1 ]; then
   DRYRUN='--dry-run'
fi
if [ $OutputAsMuchInfoAsPossible -eq 1 ]; then
   VERBOSE='--verbose'
fi

lftp -f "
open $HOST
user $USER $PASS
lcd $PCFOLDER
mirror $DRYRUN $REVERSE $IGNORESUBDIRS $DELETE $REMOVE $CONTINUEFILES $ONLYNEWER $CopyMoreThanOneFileSimultaneously --use-cache $ExcludeParams $VERBOSE $DIRECTORIES
bye
"
```

Comment: This site helped me to create that script: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/lftp-mirror-example/ (see `A complete list of lftp mirror command options`)

Comment: This seems a perfect answer - I cannot understand why I did not see it when it was written more than a year ago. My problem is still waiting for a good solution and I will try this next. Thank you!

Comment: You can mark it as "solution" if you want.

Comment: I need to try it and then I will!

Comment: Very impressive! edits were simple and works perfect! Very good and thank you a lot! and I am very sorry I did not see your answer before.

Comment: is there a specific reason, you did not provide for an `include-glob`. It would come handy and I think I see how to add it. Would you want to put this on github or should I do it - i think it is generally useful.

Comment: Good idea. I have done it https://github.com/michaelhutter/FtpSync.sh

Comment: What exactly is a `include-glob`?

Comment: inclde-glob is similar (not quite) to the exclude-globs (your excludeParams), only one has to exclude first everything before then including.... i forked from your gitub and tried it and it works, but is not really nice. it uploads only the html, jpg, and css. what is your opinion?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I can see that you forked my repo, but I cannot see any changes. Maybe you didn't push them to GitHub?

Comment: I did not like my solution well enoughand do not think it is generally useful, therefore I did not make a pull request. Additionally, there is the problem of the script contains the passwords in clear. I will post a new question for this - perhaps you have a solution!